# Return data from angular strap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-strap

I am sorry if this has been already asked, but is it possible to return data from angular strap modal, and if so, could anyone provide short code snippet how to do so?

There is very nice option to return data from angular-ui modal, but I was not able to find the strap-way.
Thank you very much for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a simple way to achieve this and the API is just like angular-ui modal.

You decorate the `$modal` service:

```
.config(['$provide', function($provide) {

    $provide.decorator('$modal', ['$q', '$rootScope', '$delegate', function ($q, $rootScope, $delegate)
    {
        return function returnAResultWhenClosingTheModal(options)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            if (!options.scope) {
                options.scope = $rootScope.$new();
            }

            options.scope.$close = function(result)
            {
                deferred.resolve(result);
                this.$hide();
            };

            // Call the real $modal service to create the modal
            var modal = $delegate(options);

            modal.result = deferred.promise;

            return modal;
        }
    }
    ]);
}])
```

To create a modal is the same as always except now each modal has a `result` property which is a promise that gets resolved when the modal is closed:

```
var myModal = $modal(modalOptions);

myModal.result.then(function(result)
{
    // I now have access to the result the modal closed with.
});
```

In the modal controller you simply call the new `$close` method on the `$scope` with the result you want to return:

```
// In the controller
$scope.$close(resultToReturn);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can return any data from your `angular-strap` modal very easy.


Suppose you have some object, that should be updated after modal's submit. For example, you have a controller, that popups your modal. All you have to do is to define some handler, that should update your data, pass this handler to youp modal via `resolve` option and call this handler in modal's controller.


Example:

This controller contains user details and shows modal for change this data.

```
app.controller('userDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.userDetails = {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith'
    };

    $scope.showChangeUserDetailsModal = function() {
        var options = {
            userDetails: angular.copy($scope.userDetails),
            submit: function(result) {
                $scope.userDetails = angular.copy(result);
            }
        };
        $modal({
            controller: 'changeUserDetailsCtrl',
            contentTemplate: '', //Here is your template with some input fields
            show: true,
            resolve: {
                options: function() {
                    return options;
                }
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

Modal's controller calls handler `submit`, passing result of modal's work.

```
app.controller('changeUserDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', 'options', function($scope, options) {
    $scope.userDetailsDraft = options.userDetails;

    $scope.submitChanges = function() {
        options.submit($scope.userDetailsDraft);
        $scope.$hide(); //Close modal after submit
    };
}]);
```